# Why does "levels" appear when I run this command?

Tags: r, dataframe

So this isn't really a problem but more of wanting to understand how R works. When I run e$s, it shows "levels" but I thought this was only for factors. Furthermore, I don't see "levels" when I run e$n, could someone explain why?

> e = data.frame(n,s,b)

n s  b

2 aa   a

3 bb  bb

5 cc ccc

This is what the data frame looks like.

outputs

> e$n
>
> [1] 2 3 5
>
> e$s
>
> [1] aa bb cc
>
> Levels: aa bb cc

Comment: That's because s _is_ a factor.  You need `e = data.frame(n,s,b, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: so is a string vector by default also a factor? Thanks for the reply btw!

Comment: Not exactly.  A string vector is not a factor,  but when you put one into a data frame, it will be made into a factor by default.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Do you know if there is any particular reason for this?

Comment: @JonDoe: Although the scope of R has grown, remember that it was originally developed to as a tool for running statistical tests, and data.frames was the main method of supplying variables to such tests. In this context it makes complete sense for character vectors to be interpreted as categorical variables by default.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: @G5W, post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Levels are only for factors. Even if `s` was character vector before you put it into the data.frame,  once you created `e`, it was a factor. Notice this line from the help page for `data.frame`

> stringsAsFactors
>   logical: should character vectors be converted to
>   factors? The ‘factory-fresh’ default is TRUE,

If you want to get characters rather than a factor, you need to specify `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

```
e = data.frame(n,s,b, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```